# Display array value with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need to display the values in my UsersData array, same as array numbers, but I can not do that in ReactJS.

Here's an example available in CodeSandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n08n2m7mpj

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const usersData = [
    {
      total: 3,
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tania", username: "floppydiskette" },
        { id: 2, name: "Craig", username: "siliconeidolon" },
        { id: 3, name: "Ben", username: "benisphere" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      {numbers.map((number, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{number}</li>
      ))}

      {usersData.length > 0 ? (
        usersData.map((data, index) => <div key={index}>Nome: {data.name}</div>)
      ) : (
        <div>No users </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Would be easier if `usersData` was an object rather than an array: https://codesandbox.io/s/8zk0n46z90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `usersData` is an array containing one element (an object)

2) You need to iterate over the data array of that object and display the value of name property for each its objects.

```
{usersData[0].data.length > 0 ? (
  usersData[0].data.map((obj, index) => <div key={index}>Nome: {obj.name}</div>)
) : (
  <div>No users </div>
)}
```

[Forked update](https://codesandbox.io/s/ooo9rrv9w5)

Answer (score 1):

Your usersData is an array usersData=[] which contains an object usersData=[{}] which itself contains the array of data usersData=[{data: []}] so you need to change your variable to an object and use the map function on the array of data inside it like so

```
    const usersData = {
      total: 3,
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tania", username: "floppydiskette" },
        { id: 2, name: "Craig", username: "siliconeidolon" },
        { id: 3, name: "Ben", username: "benisphere" }
      ]
    };
```

and your loop would become

```
      {usersData.data.length > 0 ? (
        usersData.data.map((user, index) => <div key={index}>Nome: {user.name}</div>)
      ) : (
        <div>No users </div>
      )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
  usersData[0].data.map(({name}, index) => <div key={index}>Nome: {name}</div>)
```

Becaise you are not accessing the data array in your code above

Comment: usersData seems to be an array

Comment: I've tried this, but when I include the "data" value before the "map" function, it generates an error.

Answer (score -1):

```
usersData.map((userData, index) => {
     return userData.data.map(item => {
         return <div key={index + item.id}>Nome: {item.name}</div>;
     });
});
```

Comment: Look at the data structure again.